# How to safely cast a python variable to a literal type?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Say I have an arbitrary value, how do I check that the value is a valid value for a given literal type?

Some explanation or useful examples what i expected:

```py
KnownFormats = Literal["json", "py", "txt"]
def do_something(format: KnownFormats): ...
def is_known_format(format: Any): ...
```

I expected this to work, similar to the `isinstance` method:

```py
value = str() # some runtime value
# similar to: if isinstance(value, KnownFormats):
if is_known_format(value):
    # This is not allowed:
    # Type "str" cannot be assigned to type "KnownFormats"
    do_something(value)
```

Or something like this:

```py
def cast_format(str: Any) -> Optional[KnownFormats]: ...
unknown: None = cast_format("what?")
json_format: Literal["json"] = cast_format("json")
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use an `Enum`?  The enum semantics for this are really nice.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use an `Enum`, whose built-in constructor behaves mostly like the `cast_format` you're envisioning (except that it raises on an error instead of returning `None`):

```
from enum import Enum

class KnownFormat(Enum):
    JSON = "json"
    PY = "py"
    TXT = "txt"

def cast_format(format: str) -> KnownFormat | None:
    try:
        return KnownFormat(format)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Comment: Careful about shadowing the name of the built-in [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) function. Though that goes for the OP's code as well.